# How to change strimzi cruise control default topic replication factor to 3?

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

I need to increase the Strimzi cruise control default topic (modeltrainingsamples, partitionmetricsamples) replication factor to 3, tried it below configurations, but it doesn't work.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.3.1
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
    - name: plain
      port: 9092
      type: internal
      tls: false  
    - name: tls
      port: 9093
      type: internal
      tls: true
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 3
      min.insync.replicas: 2
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.3"
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  entityOperator:
  topicOperator: {}
  userOperator: {}
  cruiseControl:
    config:
      cruise.control.modeltrainingsamples.topic: strimzi.cruisecontrol.modeltraingsamples   
      cruise.control.modeltraingsamples.topic.replication.factor: 3
      cruise.control.modeltrainingsamples.topic.min.insync.replicas: 2
      cruise.control.modeltrainingsamples.topic: strimzi.cruisecontrol.partitionmetricsamples
      cruise.control.partitionmetricsamples.topic.replication.factor: 3
      cruise.control.partitionmetricsamples.topic.min.insync.replicas: 2
```

Could you suggest changing the default topic replication factor of strimzi cruise control topics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For changing the default replication factor of the sample store topics [1], `partition.metric.sample.store.topic` and `broker.metric.sample.store.topic`, configure the Cruise Control config section of the `Kafka` resource like this:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  ...
  cruiseControl:
    config: 
      sample.store.topic.replication.factor: 3
```

Note that the cruiseControl.config section of the `Kafka` resource can take most of the configurations listed in the Cruise Control wiki [2]. For more information checkout the Strimzi docs here [1]

[1] https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/configuring.html#property-cruise-control-config-reference

[2] https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control/wiki/Configurations#kafkasamplestore-configurations

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. got your point. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @kyguy, thank you for this clarification. Do you know if there are any specific reasons to make Cruise Control use the replication factor of 2 instead of 3?